# Sum a consulta a partir de la segunda fila

Tags: sql, sql-server, tsql, transact-sql

como puedo realizar un som a partir de la segunda fila

por ejemplo tengo este resultado

```
Cuenta    Numero    Fecha
43424234    1   8/9/2022
43424234    1   8/10/2022
43424234    1   8/11/2022
43424234    1   8/12/2022
```

pero quiero sumar a partir de la segunda fila, a modo de que me quede asi el resultado

```
Cuenta    Numero    Fecha
43424234    3   8/9/2022
```

El script es algo básico de ejemplo

```
SELECT Cuenta, Numero, Fecha
FROM Tabla
```

Comment: Quieres que el resultado tenga la primera fecha ?? (la que fue saltada)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo primero que necesitas es una forma para identificar de forma sencilla de identificar la primer fila para poder excluirla. Una forma sencilla es usando la función `ROW_NUMBER()`.

Dejo un ejemplo con la creación de datos de prueba.

```
CREATE TABLE Prueba(
    Cuenta  int,
    Numero  int,
    Fecha   date
);
INSERT INTO Prueba
VALUES
(43424234, 1, '20220809'),
(43424234, 1, '20220810'),
(43424234, 1, '20220811'),
(43424234, 1, '20220812');

WITH ctePrueba AS(
    SELECT *,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER( /*PARTITION BY Cuenta*/ ORDER BY Fecha) AS rn
    FROM Prueba
)
SELECT Cuenta,
    SUM( Numero) AS Numero,
    MIN( Fecha)
FROM ctePrueba
WHERE rn > 1
GROUP BY Cuenta;
```